# No automatic sign_in after modifying devise registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I initially wanted to send my user to a different page after sign_up. This works now, as I created a registrations controller. The problem now is that the user is prompted to login right after sign_up. Of course I want him to be automatically signed_in after sign_up. Any idea how I can fix that? I found this explanation but both answers do not work for me: [Rails: Devise login after sign up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457498/rails-devise-login-after-sign-up).

Here is my registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def start_date
    @user =current_user
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    update_attrs = [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :start_date]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:applications, :job_category, :job_status])
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/profiles/new' # Or :prefix_to_your_route
  end

end
```

here are my application Logs after signup:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_up?job_category=IT+%26+Development&job_status=Other+Category&vacancy_id=general+application" for ::1 at 2019-08-08 15:32:17 +0200
Processing by RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"job_category"=>"IT & Development", "job_status"=>"Other Category", "vacancy_id"=>"general application"}
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 174ms (Views: 171.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2019-08-08 15:32:32 +0200
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Rb06/S6dB019mw8I46x0tJytVG7HNeVV23ZbuX/9Ykb9amYwI3bCLlk8AqNjTEGAR0qTy6rlCNZE1U6w8skslA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"testtesttest@test.de", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "applications"=>"\#{general application}", "job_category"=>"IT & Development", "job_status"=>"Other Category", "terms"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Unpermitted parameter: :terms
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "testtesttest@test.de"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (6.9ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at", "applications", "job_category", "job_status") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "testtesttest@test.de"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$MlDweUU00bKQsNyA81/Cuu/o9HQSYJHM8FCInvVSaYVspvcs36oMS"], ["created_at", "2019-08-08 13:32:32.764097"], ["updated_at", "2019-08-08 13:32:32.764097"], ["applications", "{{\"general application\"}}"], ["job_category", "IT & Development"], ["job_status", "Other Category"]]
UserMailer#welcome: processed outbound mail in 0.2ms
   (8.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/profiles/new
Completed 302 Found in 316ms (ActiveRecord: 16.2ms)


Started GET "/profiles/new" for ::1 at 2019-08-08 15:32:32 +0200
Processing by ProfilesController#new as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2019-08-08 15:32:32 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_flashes.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 198ms (Views: 196.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you share the application logs?

Comment: @Rthi, done please see above.

Answer (score 0):

Change permitted params from:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
update_attrs = [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :start_date]
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:applications, :job_category, :job_status])      
end
```

to:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
update_attrs = [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :start_date]
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [ update_attrs, :applications, :job_category, :job_status])
end
```

And I think in profiles controller has a problem with  before_action :authenticate_user! .
In terminal redirect has work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with terms, in your terminal:

```
 Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
 Unpermitted parameter: :terms
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try changing the `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` to `protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true`

Ref: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers

Devise by default signout the session if the request is unverified.

Ref: from devise code(Devise::Controllers::Helpers),

```
# Overwrite Rails' handle unverified request to sign out all scopes,
      # clear run strategies and remove cached variables.
      def handle_unverified_request
        super # call the default behaviour which resets/nullifies/raises
        request.env["devise.skip_storage"] = true
        sign_out_all_scopes(false)
      end
```

2. Try this out if the first one solves the issue,  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2734 for solving the issue,

Comment: when I do the first, it gives me an error after signup. (Session Key missing). The second link did not help either. Any other suggestions? Or a trick to fix it?

Comment: Can you share what the error you are getting exactly @Sabrina?,  Sharing app logs would be better.

Comment: here ist the error (this is also what the app logs say): ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in RegistrationsController#create. So he does not even create a user here.

Comment: is `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` added in application.html.erb (i.e layout)

Comment: https://recalll.co/ask/v/topic/ruby-on-rails-ActionController%3A%3AInvalidAuthenticityToken-in-RegistrationsController-create/5a1fd01d1126f41a378b5d39

Comment: i added it but it shows the same error message as before. I should mention that the login after signup used to work before I created the registration controller. Looks like this messed up my code.

Comment: wait one sec. i have an idea what it could be.

Comment: Found my mistake. Super idiotic of me. In my sign-up view I handed an authenticity-token. But the same one for any registration. Aboslutely stupid of me. Sorry for wasting your time...!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:applications, :job_category, :job_status]

To this:
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:applications, :job_category, :job_status, :terms]

Comment: thanks that was correct. but it did not fix the actual problem: That the user does not login after signup.